# Why does CardView Shadow not update while being translated by x?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I'm using a MultiViewPager with 5 card views inside.

When the card comes from the side to the centre then once it hits the centre a darker shadow appears on the left and right of the card. The pop is really noticeable.

I was wondering if here is a way to gradually update the shadow.

Also if this helps I'm using PageTransformer to move the card up by its Y axis when it gets to the middle.